# My app crashed when clicking new dependency question. I don't know what is the error and how to solved it

Tags: java, android

`Error`
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.login, PID: 6969
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.login/com.example.login.NavigationDrawer}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.getHeaderView(int)' on a null object reference
at com.example.login.ui.questionnaire.QuestionnaireFragment.onCreateView(QuestionnaireFragment.java:80)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2995)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:523)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1374)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2841)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2777)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3020)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:394)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:260)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:295)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:274)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:784)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:999)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:999)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
at com.example.login.databinding.ActivityNavigationDrawerBinding.inflate(ActivityNavigationDrawerBinding.java:54)
at com.example.login.databinding.ActivityNavigationDrawerBinding.inflate(ActivityNavigationDrawerBinding.java:48)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.login.NavigationDrawer.onCreate(NavigationDrawer.java:42)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873

```
Java Code

package com.example.login;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import com.example.login.databinding.ActivityNavigationDrawerBinding;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
public class NavigationDrawer extends AppCompatActivity {
private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
private ActivityNavigationDrawerBinding binding;
private String username;
private EditText etUsername;
Pref pref;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
pref = new Pref(getApplicationContext());
//get username from login page
username = pref.getUsername();
//System.out.println("username in 2nd  "+username);
binding = ActivityNavigationDrawerBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
//setContentView(binding.navView);
setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarNavigationDrawer.toolbar);
binding.appBarNavigationDrawer.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
.setAction("Action", null).show();
}
});
DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
// Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
// menu should be considered as top level destinations.
mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
R.id.nav_questionnaire, R.id.nav_submitsurvey, R.id.nav_responses, R.id.nav_imagecapture, R.id.nav_dashboard)
.setOpenableLayout(drawer)
.build();
 NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_navigation_drawer);
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation_drawer, menu);
//display welcome username
etUsername = findViewById(R.id.welcomeUsername);
 etUsername.setText(username);
 Button button_log_out = findViewById(R.id.button_log_out);
button_log_out.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
logoutDialog();
}
});
return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
 NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_navigation_drawer);
return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
 || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
public void logoutDialog() {
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialog.setTitle("LogOut Alert!");
alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure want to LogOut this Application?");
alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
  pref.setLogin("no");
dialog.dismiss();
Intent intent = new Intent(NavigationDrawer.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
}
});
alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
 dialog.dismiss();
 }
        });
alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: According to your log, you have a NullPointerException

Comment: `NavigationView.getHeaderView(int)` needs a `NavigationView`, to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

you have a NullPointerException. You should check whether the data you receive is full. For example
if(data != null){
.
.
.
...
}

Comment: Cant understand

Comment: @PrasanthM if you can't understand that, you should learn the basics of java before trying to create android apps